# How can i update in background my permanent notification?

Tags: android, background-process, android-notifications, batterylevel, background-foreground

My notification shows the battery level. When i close the app the percentage in the notification doesn't update its state. I don't know how i can do so now i post the notification code and i hope someone help me

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);
    notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Battery Stats Informations");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText("Battery level: " + level + "%"
            + " " + "Temp.: " + temperature + "°C");
    notificationBuilder.setTicker("Informazioni batteria");
    notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_small_not);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            MainActivity.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    Notification notification = new Notification();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE;

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTIFICATION_ID,
            notificationBuilder.build());
```

I tried everything but nothing goes. How can i do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should create a service if you want to update the notification when your app is not working.
[You can check out android developer website](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service)

Comment: So, you're telling me that in in my case it's not possible update the notification when the app is closed?

Comment: Yes, because whenever another activity comes to foreground your app goes to paused or closed state. This is how activity lifecycle works.

Comment: Do you think i can just copy my notification code in a service? I don't know hoe exactly do it really :(. I need a broadcastreceiver also in the service i think right?

Comment: I am not really experienced in services but you can find all your answers on android developer website: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html